# How to add a Google search box in a desktop application?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a simple desktop application in java which shows the currently running services.
I want to add a Google search bar at the top, which can directly open the Google Search Result (web page) in the default browser for the entered keyword in the application.

Answer (score 4):

You should get `query_string` value from input box then use the following:

```
try {
  java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
  java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI( "http", "google.com", 
    "/search?q=" + query_string );
  desktop.browse( uri );
} catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: `query_string` Note you might have to encode that string.  E.G. `jtable java sort` should become `jtable+java+sort`, but if tacked on the end of an URL will become something like `jtable%20java%20sort`

Comment: @Sanjay it's very bad advice. There are many other special characters. However, I believe java.net.URI will escape them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I am not getting the desired results. It opens the Google page but not the search result page for the specified query_string.

Comment: What's url of page that is opened in browser?